# Mongo 3.4+ - Areas with subareas

Tags: mongodb

I want a collection with areas. Some areas have subareas

```
- Greece
-- Thessaloniki
-- Athens
-- Mykonos
```

I want all of them to have unique mongo id

What is the best way to make it?

Each area/subarea have to be a document with parent_area_id?

or

is better to keep the real structure? How can i search for one area if some of them is subdocuments?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing this in the mongo shell.  I would not suggest creating a separate _id field for each of them.  If i were you i would create a document for each country then a subdocument for each area.  But without more specifics thats all i can say.

If you use the country for the _id field it would look something like this.

```
db.collection.insert({"_id":"Greece","Areas":["Thessaloniki","Athens","Mykonos"]})
```

If you would like to add elements to each area you should do something like this then add.

```
db.collection.insert( { _id: "Greece", 
    "Areas":[{"Thessaloniki":
                {"zipcode":12345,"population":384856}},
             {"Athens":{"zipcode":12345}},
             {"Mykonos":{"zipcode":12345}}]}
```